# Android set background color button pressed

Tags: android, selector, android-imagebutton, android-shape

I would like to change the background color of my ImageButton on pressed event.

Here is what i am done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/rose_normal" />
    <solid
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/rose_fonce" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1sp"
        android:color="@color/rose_fonce" />

</shape>
```

My button is well in "rose_normal" color, but never in "rose_fonce" color on press.

Where is the problem ?

***EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED :***

**Create one xml file called background_rounded_button.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button_rose_fonce" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button_rose_fonce" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button_rose_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

**rounded_button_rose_fonce.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/rose_fonce" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1sp"
        android:color="@color/rose_fonce" />

</shape>
```

**rounded_button_rose_normal.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/rose_normal" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1sp"
        android:color="@color/rose_fonce" />

</shape>
```

And finally, apply background for the button :

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/all_annonce_button_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_button.xml"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are **not using a selector, but a shape.**

Try this code (button_selector.xml, put it in your `drawable` folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/rose_fonce" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/rose_fonce" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/rose_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

When setting this selector **as the background** of a `Button`, it will have the "rose_normal" color in normal state, and the "rose_fonce" color when pressed or selected.

Example:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but i have lost the oval shape of my button. How can i re-add this oval ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos,Try to set your custom two ovel image instead of color.